# JTable & Filereader Implementation

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtable

Populating `JTable` using `FileReader`

I have looked over the Internet, however, have been unsuccessful in finding a good tutorial or example.

Comment: The short answer is "Yes". The long is, it depends.  What is the format of the file?  How do you differentiate between each column in the file? Is the column titles part of the file?

Comment: Your `HighScores2` class already has `BufferedReader over FileReader` implementation.  What **component** do you want to populate with your text?

Comment: You're suffering from the common fallacy of looking for too specific a tutorial. You're looking for a tutorial that does X, Y, and Z, all together when instead you're ignoring the tutorials that explain how to do X, how to do Y, and how to do Z. Those tutorials are out there including how to read in data from a file, how to use data to create a TableModel, and how to use a TableModel to display data in a JTable. I suggest that you go to these basic tutorials because the combined tutorial doesn't and can't exist, and then use your own knowledge and brain to put the ideas together to your use.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. @MadProgrammer It is a .txt file i just have the one column for now. No they are not part of the file.

Comment: How can it only be one column. Based on the heading you want a "player" and "score" to be in the table. Therefore your data file would need two columns. That is you need a delimeter between the data so you know what text is the name and what text is the score.

Comment: Please cite the post to which you refer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem is a translation problem.  How to get from state A to state B.  You need to get the contents of the file into a state that it will be possible to wrap it in a `TableModel` of some kind.

I would start with

- [Basic IO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)
- [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Once you have the ability to read the file and store it's content in some meaningful manner (I'd create a nice class that was capable of handling the data for each row and place them all into something like an `ArrayList`, but that's me), then I'd work out how to get that data into the table.

Once you have the data in some kind of structure, getting into the table is relatively simple.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i have updated my post. would really appreciate if you had a look at it.